How to interpret the physical meaning of cointegration vectors of log prices in real world
I'm trying to understand the physical meaning of cointegration vectors of log prices in the real world.
For example, if I have two assets $A$ and $B$, and Johansen test gives us a cointegration coefficient of [1 -1] for their log prices:$$log(A)-log(B)=\eta$$ When we convert this relationship back to real prices to understand its physical meaning, we have $$\frac{A}{B}=e^\eta$$ This makes sense because a fixed ratio between two real assets is intuitive.
However, for cointegration coefficient other than [1 -1], say [1 -2]: $$log(A)-2log(B)=\eta$$ when we convert it back to real price, we will have a relationship of $$\frac{A}{B^2} = e^\eta$$ This is nonintuitive to understand. How is this relationship possible between two assets in the real world like this: An asset's price is quadratic to another asset's price?
It is even worse if more assets are involved in the cointegration, giving relationships like $(A^2 B^3)/(C^4 D^{1.5}) = \eta$ in the real price.
In other word, for example, in a pairs trading, if the cointegration vector is found to be [1 -2] of the log prices, what ratio should I trade for the real price? It should not be [1 -2].
I understand how cointegration works with log prices, but I'm struggling to grasp its real-world meaning. Could someone shed some light on this?

I found this answer on QSE https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/41346/cointegration-on-prices-or-difference-of-prices with a good link in the comment: https://epchan.blogspot.com/2013/11/cointegration-trading-with-log-prices.html

@Kermittfrog I have read this website before, but I think it doesn't answer my question. What I am confusing is how to interpret the cointegration coefficient for log prices other than [1 -1]. If the cointegration coefficient for log price is [1 -1], we have /=
in real price: a fixed ratio between two real assets is intuitive. However, for cointegration coefficient other than [1 -1], say [1 -2], we will have a relationship of /2=
. I could not understand how such a relationship exist. stock B is quadratic to stock A? We don't have such a relationship in real world, right?

One possibility is you have not explored a good amount of data, and in a small region $sqrt(A)$ can approximate $A$, and if there is an anomaly in the data, $sqrt(A)$ can very well be a candidate. You will probably observe that the likelihood function is very flat in this case, meaning the data does not imply a massive confidence on the result that you have, and it is worthwhile revisiting data.
For example, say the relationship is $B=2A$. Now if A is in [10000,10050], you can say $B=200*sqrt(A)$ and really the data will not be able to say one is much better than the other. If I add an anomaly here which is (10025,20025), it will be more difficult to determine the relationship.
It is very much likely that the result is due to range of A not explored thoroughly. If you are keen that the true relationship is $B=sqrt(A)$, then it is not possible to explain without looking at the underlying factors that govern $A$ and $B$.

Consider a cointegration vector of $[1, -2]$ for the log prices of assets $A$ and $B$. This implies the relationship $\log(A) - 2 \log(B) = \eta$, where $\eta$ is a stationary error term. Exponentiating this equation, we get $\frac{A}{B^2} = e^\eta$, which represents the long-run equilibrium relationship between the price levels of assets $A$ and $B$.
It's important to note that this relationship doesn't imply a direct quadratic relationship between the prices of the two assets. The cointegration vector $[1, -2]$ does not mean that asset $B$ is twice as volatile as asset $A$. Instead, it indicates that in the long run, the ratio of the price of asset $A$ to the square of the price of asset $B$ tends to revert to a constant value, $e^\eta$.
In practical terms, a cointegration vector of $[1, -2]$ suggests that if the price of asset $B$ increases, the price of asset $A$ needs to increase proportionally to the square of $B$ to maintain the long-run equilibrium relationship. This does not directly translate to percentage changes in prices or relative volatility. The volatility of each asset needs to be assessed independently through other means like historical price variance analysis.
For trading strategies, the cointegration vector $[1, -2]$ suggests a potential pairs trading strategy where one would hold one unit of asset $A$ and short two units of asset $B$. This strategy aims to profit from the mean-reversion of the ratio $\frac{A}{B^2}$ to its long-run equilibrium value, $e^\eta$. This is not based on the assumption that asset $B$ is twice as volatile as asset $A$ but on the expectation that the ratio $\frac{A}{B^2}$ will revert to its mean.
